# Randomly selecting elements in an array only once each while keeping track of their original position - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am currently coding in JavaScript for a project where I need to create modified arrays based on an original one. I am having an issue when it comes to randomly selecting the elements of the original array that need to be modified. For the project's purposes, I need to keep track of the original position of each elements, but I also cannot pick the same element twice.

So far, I had been randomly selecting an item using this:

```js
var originalArray = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5];

var modifiedArray = [];

var copyOriginalArray = originalArray;

var score = Math.floor(Math.random() * copyOriginalArray.length);

var targetScore = copyOriginalArray[score];

targetProfile.push(targetScore);

copyOriginalArray.splice(score, 1);
```

But the issue is that, while it does randomly select an item and ensures that it will not be selected again, it does not allow me to keep track of the original position of the items. Also, since some of the items may be the same, I can't simply trace them back to the original array.

What do you suggest doing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not an answer to your main question, but be careful with `var copyOriginalArray = originalArray;` that is not a copy of the array - it's two variables referencing the same array!

Comment: you have a syntax error defining the arrays, missing the `=`

Comment: why not take an array of indices, randomize it and take it for picking values.

Comment: Also, it would really help us understand what you're trying to do if your code actually ran. You have variables that aren't defined but seem important, like `copyUser`,  making things confusing

Comment: Sorry about these mistakes, I wrote new code and also copied some code from my project and forgot to modify the names of the variables. I hope it's clearer now! The issue about running it is that the code is actually much more complex and I am just trying to simplify it to address this specific issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do a new array called `positions` containing the indexes:

```
positions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

when you modify a position in the original array, you also modify it on the positions array, at the end you will have for example:

```
positions = [4,2,3,1,6,7,5]
```

and you will know which that the 1st element in the array was the 4th element in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate array of numbers 0..(array.length - 1), shuffle it, and then use that to pick the items one-by-one:

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 1; i -= 1) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

var originalArray = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5];

var indices = originalArray.map(function (x, i) { return i });

console.log('Indices:', indices);

shuffle(indices);

console.log('Shuffled indices:', indices);

console.log('Original array in random order:');

for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(originalArray[indices[i]]);
}
```

Another option would be to simply make a copy of the original array and shuffle that. The downside of this approach is that you don't know which item in the copy comes from which position in the original array (and it sounds like you need that).

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 1; i -= 1) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

var originalArray = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5];

var copiedArray = originalArray.slice();

shuffle(copiedArray);

console.log('Shuffled array:', copiedArray);
console.log('Original array:', originalArray);
```